# How to fix a test failing on org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException Error creating bean with name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a properly working Spring boot application. in the Spring boot application class i have these 2 beans:

```
@Bean
    public StatsdMeterRegistry graphiteRegistry(StatsdConfig statsdConfig) {
       statsdMeterRegistry = StatsdMeterRegistry
                    .builder(statsdConfig)
                    .nameMapper(new GraphiteHierarchicalNameMapper(HOST_TAG))
                    .build();
            return statsdMeterRegistry;
        }

@Bean
MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags() {
            InetAddress localHost;
            try {
                localHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                log.error("Failed to get the host name");
                return null;
            }
            return registry -> registry.config()
                 .commonTags(HOST_TAG, localHost.getHostName() + "_" + SERVICE_NAME);
            }
```

These bean are working fine during run time but fail during test time with:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphiteRegistry' during test.

My test clss looks something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(IntentModelingController.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.yml")
public class IntentModelingControllerTest {


    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private IntentModelingService intentModelingService;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    private Gson gson = new Gson();
```

Any advice on how to make these beans visible during test time ?

Edit: if i comment the first bean and leave the second bean as is - the test run well.

Edit#2: The difference between the 1st bean which cause the issue and the 2nd bean which is fine is that the 1st bean requires a parameter:Parameter 0 of method graphiteRegistry in yyy.xxx.intentmodeling.server.IntentModelingApplication required a bean of type 'io.micrometer.statsd.StatsdConfig' that could not be found.

SOLVED by adding 2 fields to the test:

```
@MockBean
private StatsdMeterRegistry statsdMeterRegistry;
@MockBean
StatsdConfig statsdConfig;
```

Comment: Have you tried importing the configuration that defines the beans?

Comment: Move the registry configuration to a separate `@Configuration` class so that it won't be loaded during the test.

Comment: solved by mocking the bean in the test!

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the configuration class that defines the beans on top of your test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(IntentModelingController.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.yml")
@Import(YourConfig.class)
```

Another possible issue could be that the `@Bean` is detected, but the `graphiteRegistry` method throws an exception. This could happen, for example, due to **missing properties** (I see you defined an application-test.yml, does it contain all the needed properties to instantiate your bean?).

Comment: I did use the @ContextConfiguration in my unit tests in order to import config classes.

Comment: Ok, please investigate if you are missing any properties.

Comment: The configuration class that defines my bean is the main class of this spring boot application, i tried adding it as @Import(IntentModelingApplication.class) but it failed the same way. i also made sure that all the needed configurations are at application-test.yml

Comment: If you are using Spring boot, try replacing `@WebMvcTest(IntentModelingController.class)` with `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: Making the replacment didn't work, but i found that the difference between the 1st bean which cause the issue and the 2nd bean which is fine is that the 1st bean requires a parameter:Parameter 0 of method graphiteRegistry in yyy.xxx.intentmodeling.server.IntentModelingApplication required a bean of type 'io.micrometer.statsd.StatsdConfig' that could not be found.

Comment: Yes, considering your current declarations, all your dependencies need to be available for tests as well.

Comment: Solved! thanks alexrolea ! i guess the bean was there is the test all along but it failed since it didn't have it's dependencies, in this case parameters, solved by adding 2 fields to the test.